# Множественный выбор в ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, expandablelistview

В разметку активности добавил `ExpandableListView` . Как я могу добавить множественный выбор для каждого элемента подгруппы и впоследствии добавлять все выбранные элементы в `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 0):

`ExpandableListView` из коробки не поддерживает множественный выбор. Можно извести сотни строк *обучая* его к множественному селекту/чойсу, а можно просто взять проект из гитхаба и использовать его.

[ListBoost](https://github.com/kemallette/ListBoost)

Comment: Как я могу добавить его в проект?

Comment: И если не сложно, то можете показать как его иницилизировать и использовать?